# How to fillter autosuggest options using typeahead.js

Tags: typeahead, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am using twitter typeahead.js and I would like to filter autosuggest results by recipe_type. When recipe_type is 1 then suggest me first three options else if recipe_type is 2 then suggest me five other options...

My json array looks like:

```
[
{ "recipe_type": "1", "value": 1 , "text": "Čebula"},
{ "recipe_type": "1", "value": 2 , "text": "Paradižnik"},
{ "recipe_type": "1", "value": 3 , "text": "Juha"},
{ "recipe_type": "2", "value": 4 , "text": "Česen"},
{ "recipe_type": "2", "value": 5 , "text": "Grah"},
{ "recipe_type": "2", "value": 6 , "text": "Sol"},
{ "recipe_type": "2", "value": 7 , "text": "Poper"},
{ "recipe_type": "2", "value": 8 , "text": "Ješprenj"},
]
```

My searcher code is :

```
var elt = $('#search_input');

elt.tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    freeInput: false
});


elt.tagsinput('input').typeahead({
    valueKey: 'text',
    //prefetch: 'assets/js/cities.json',
    prefetch :
    {
        url: 'assets/js/file.json',
        matcher: function (item) {
            return item.recipe_type == '1'
        }
    },
    /*template: '<p>{{text}}</p>',*/
    engine: Hogan,
    matcher: function(item) {
        return item.recipe_type == '1'
    }
}).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {
        this.tagsinput('add', datum);
        this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
    }, elt));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work better provided you also remove the trailing `,` from your Json array.

```
elt.tagsinput('input').typeahead({
    valueKey: 'recipe_type',
    prefetch :'assets/js/file.json',
    template: '<p>{{text}}</p>',
    engine: Hogan
}).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {
        this.tagsinput('add', datum);
        this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
}, elt));
```

The main issue was that valueKey should be set to the value you want to use as your key to search your list of Json values.  Using that removes the need to use matcher (which I don't actually see listed in the docs anywhere).

Comment: please see my answer, i think that my question wasn't clear a lot. In my answer you will see what i want...

Comment: hm, after i pick different recipe_type (1,2,3,4,5...) i want that my typeahead suggest me appropriate results.

Example: if user choose recipe_type 1 in dropdown suggest there must be values Čebula, Paradižnik, Juha, if user choose recipe_type 2 there must be values Česen, Grah, Sol, Poper, Ješprenj. Understand?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is bellow. When i click on button in div with id #recipe_type i destroy current typeahead object and create new one with different recipe_type filter. Is there maybe better solution?

```
var recipe_type = "1";

var elt = $('#search_input');

elt.tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    freeInput: false
});


elt.tagsinput('input').typeahead({
    valueKey: 'text',
    prefetch: {
        url: 'assets/js/cities.json',

        filter: function (data) {
            var dataSet = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var receivedData = data[i];
                if(receivedData.recipe_type == recipe_type){
                    dataSet.push(receivedData);
                }

            }
            return dataSet;
        }
    },
    /*template: '<p>{{text}}</p>',*/
    engine: Hogan
}).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {
        this.tagsinput('add', datum);
        this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
    }, elt));

$('#recipe_type button').click(function(){

    $("#recipe_type button.btn-success").removeClass("btn-success"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("btn-success"); //Add "active" class to selected tab

    recipe_type = $(this).data('file')

    elt.tagsinput('input').typeahead('destroy');

    elt.tagsinput('input').typeahead({
        valueKey: 'text',
        prefetch: {
            url: 'assets/js/cities.json',

            filter: function (data) {
                var dataSet = [];

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var receivedData = data[i];
                    if(receivedData.recipe_type == recipe_type){
                        dataSet.push(receivedData);
                    }

                }
                return dataSet;
            }
        },
        engine: Hogan
    }).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {
            this.tagsinput('add', datum);
            this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
        }, elt));
});
```